# Prevent contenteditable adding div on Enter in Ionic

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a contenteditable element in `home.html`,  whenever I type some stuff and hit Enter it creates a new `<div>`:

`home.html` code

```
<div class="context_menu"><p contenteditable="true">second section</p></div>
```

How can I prevent this from happening or replace with a `<br>` tag?

There is a solution available in JS, I added the code in `home.ts' in ngOnInit as shown below, I have installed jQuery but it did not work, maybe I have copied it wrongly?

```
  ngOnInit(){

     $('div[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
       // trap the return key being pressed
       if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        // insert 2 br tags (if only one br tag is inserted the cursor won't go to the next line)
         document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
         // prevent the default behaviour of return key pressed
         console.log("pressed");
         return false;
       }
     });
```

Comment: It's wanted by design, contenteditable works like that. it will add <divs> for each line. You can force to replace, but then you will loose the new line. Could you explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: In the absence of an answer to a request for clarification, this can be closed as Unclear or Lacking A [mcve].